# Backbone large scale web application

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having trouble getting started with a large scale backbone web application, we have the API built and ready to use, and we have decided to use Backbone to create the front end. I under the Model/View/Collection organisation of Backbone, what I am struggling with is how to use the Router, a small breakdown of our app would that on the dashboard a user is greeted with a list of items. Clicking a item launches a view a view that is modal window, at this point we want the URL to change from `#dashboard` to #item/edit/9 (9 being the item id) so that the link can be emailed and the same model open for the recipient.

What are the best practices when creating a large scale backbone applications, specifically around routing and file organisation.

Comment: Try Marionette. http://marionettejs.com/. It has nice features built on Top of Backbone which will make your life much easier.

Comment: +1 for marionette - i used David Sulc's book Backbone.Marionette.js: A Gentle Introduction, and the structure he sets out with is a great stating point for managing a large application.